# SQL Server getting values from 4 tables into ONE

Tags: sql-server

I have 5 Tables :

```
1- UserAccount : Has AccountNumber field
2- Total Amount : Has AccountNumber field
3- Total Withdrawal : Has AccountNumber field
4- Total Profit : Has AccountNumber field
5- Balance : Has AccountNumber field
```

I need to get the values of [Total Amount], [Total Withdrawal], [Total Profit] & [Balance] for each user in ONE table to be like:

```
AccountNumber   Balance   Total Amount  Total Withdrawal  Total Profit
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
201               450           600              150                250
222               600           800              200                150
```

I used this query but the results isn't correct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
dbo.useraccount.AccountNumber,
dbo.useraccount.FirstName,
dbo.useraccount.SecondName,
dbo.Balance.Balance,
sum(dbo.[Total Amount].DepositTotal) AS [Total Deposit],
Sum(dbo.[Total Profit].ProfitTotal) AS [Total Profit],
Sum(dbo.[Total Withdrawal].WithdrawalTotal) AS [Total Withdrawal]

FROM
dbo.useraccount ,
dbo.Balance ,
dbo.[Total Amount] ,
dbo.[Total Profit] ,
dbo.[Total Withdrawal]
WHERE
dbo.useraccount.AccountNumber = dbo.Balance.AccountNumber AND
dbo.useraccount.AccountNumber = dbo.[Total Amount].AccountNumber AND
dbo.useraccount.AccountNumber = dbo.[Total Profit].AccountNumber AND
dbo.useraccount.AccountNumber = dbo.[Total Withdrawal].AccountNumber
GROUP BY
dbo.useraccount.AccountNumber,
dbo.useraccount.FirstName,
dbo.useraccount.SecondName,
dbo.Balance.Balance
```

Any help please?

The results i am getting is something like this:

```
AccountNumber   Balance   Total Amount  Total Withdrawal  Total Profit
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
201         5316.52    291060.00      86328.20         51150.00
220         35000.00   2086400.00     648000.00        532800.00
221         12000.00   192000.00      44548.00         44548.00
222          8500.00   76500.00       12003.75         12003.75
224          4000.00   484000.00      120780.00        120780.00
226          2393.50   48000.00       5206.50          10736.00
```

When i run this query for [Total Profit] i get correct results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
dbo.[Total Profit].AccountNumber,
Sum(dbo.[Total Profit].ProfitTotal) As [Total Deposit]

FROM
dbo.[Total Profit]
GROUP BY
dbo.[Total Profit].AccountNumber
```

Comment: Aliases man. Aliases.

Comment: results isn't correct.. Can you elavorate more? what was the expected and the result, or what is wrong about it.

Comment: Aliases would make it easier to read. You are using implicit joins, you should be making explicit joins. What is wrong with the results you get.

Comment: I will explain aliases in my answer as soon as you can explain why your desired results aren't corret.

Comment: for example Total Profit for each user is showing a huge number i dunno from where this number came from!!

Comment: Can you give us the which table has one-to-many relationship? The joins are adding your "total" values multiple times.

Comment: What makes you think the number is wrong?

Comment: What do the tables look like?

Comment: @samyi yes i think so

Comment: What makes you say this information is wrong?

Comment: @Zane coz it's wrong :) I have calculated it manually

Comment: @TamerSherif than what are the correct values? Are these the values from my query or the `SUM` query?

Comment: Run this and post the result... select count(*) as CountUserAccount from dbo.UserAccount where AccountNumber = 201;
select count(*) as CountBalance from dbo.Balance where AccountNumber = 201;
select count(*) as CountTotalAmount from dbo.[Total Amount] where AccountNumber = 201;
select count(*) as CountTotalProfit from dbo.[Total Profit] where AccountNumber = 201;
select count(*) as CountTotalWithdrawal from dbo.[Total Withdrawal] where AccountNumber = 201;

Comment: You need to post your tables structure. Right now some/all of your joins are multiplying the results, and giving you the "wrong" totals

Comment: @samyi here's the results: 1
1
5
11
7

Comment: You have duplicate accounts in your aggregated tables.

Comment: @Zane each user has numbers of deposits and withdrawals

Comment: @TamerSherif yeah but it's a total table.

Answer (score 5):

Well, given that you haven't posted your tables definition, you can do this to avoid the duplication of rows:

```
SELECT  UA.AccountNumber,
        UA.FirstName,
        UA.SecondName,
        B.Balance,
        TA.DepositTotal [Total Deposit],
        TP.ProfitTotal [Total Profit],
        TW.WithdrawalTotal [Total Withdrawal]
FROM dbo.useraccount UA
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AccountNumber, SUM(Balance) Balance
            FROM dbo.Balance
            GROUP BY AccountNumber) B
    ON UA.AccountNumber = B.AccountNumber
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AccountNumber, SUM(DepositTotal) DepositTotal
            FROM dbo.[Total Amount]
            GROUP BY AccountNumber) TA
    ON UA.AccountNumber = TA.AccountNumber
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AccountNumber, SUM(ProfitTotal) ProfitTotal
            FROM dbo.[Total Profit]
            GROUP BY AccountNumber) TP
    ON UA.AccountNumber = TP.AccountNumber
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AccountNumber, SUM(WithdrawalTotal) WithdrawalTotal
            FROM dbo.[Total Withdrawal]
            GROUP BY AccountNumber) TW
    ON UA.AccountNumber = TW.AccountNumber
```

Of course, you shouldn't need to do that aggregation for every table, only the ones that have multiple rows for each `AccountNumber`.

Comment: getting this error: [Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Balance'.

Comment: @TamerSherif Yeah, had an extra column on my `SELECT`, corrected now